# php pthreads maximum execution time

Tags: php

I am reading http://pthreads.org/ on the topic of pthreads and i have this questions.Does pthread depend on the maximum execution time set using `void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )` or can a thread run for more time than set_time_limit allows?.

Comment: Some notes: a) Running PHP in threaded mode is not suggested, timeouts are on of many reasons, it's suggested to use apache+mod_prefork or fpm b) the exact implementation depends on the environment, default on Unixes and non-threading mode is using the systems setitimer() syscall, see the manpage there for more, on windows it is using a special signaling thread c) it's a mess (like anything near the system which behaves slightly different everywhere ... while being an application meant for being embedded somewhere else ...) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running PHP in threaded mode is required to run pthreads; it's subject to the same limitations and oddities that any threaded build of PHP is.